# How can you apply '?' operator in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, operators

Does c# distinguish all three of the following:

```
int? []arr;  // array of nullable ints
int  []?arr; // nullable array of ints
int? []?arr; // nullable array of nullable ints
```

Comment: Obviously, yes. Because they are 3 different declarations. Which problem with this code do you have?

Comment: Just try what happens.  Do you have strong reason to think C# does **not** distinguish them?

Comment: Thanks. I want to make sure of it.

Comment: `int?` is [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1) struct actually, nullable array implemented using type annotations (as other NRT) in C# 8

Comment: You can always check it [yourself](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQMQB2ArgDZsCGwbMpMTbr3qlRASyYAXAPwBtALqlOUKKQC8pJjADupCTNkAGeQG5RAenNKVnAJ6kIAM03suPPvoDOI8VIXTrKBwzSxcOIT5lKDsHZy8fPSk5eQCorBCrVnD3QJinMLdeRMlvAlFREnIUUgBZAAoASloE8tIW8owcAE46qIA6ABUIAGVJKAkAc0aGk3aK7t6VHEGRscnp2bLWjoW0ldHxpimGmYSAX0IzoA==)